# orthogonality of Lagrange basis with legend nodes

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra, interpolation, orthogonal-polynomials, lagrange-interpolation

I came across the following statement and I don't know how to justify it.

If $L_i$ is a Lagrange basis, and $x$ is a zero of Legendre polynomial, then

$$ \int_{-1}^{1} L_i(x)L_j(x) dx = \delta_{ij}w_j$$

where $w_j$ are the Gauss–Legendre quadrature weights. How to justify this statement?

Comment: "$x$ is a zero of the Legendre polynomial" doesn't really make sense in this context, as it is an integration variable.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This statement is false.  The integral
$$
\int_{-1}^1 L_i(x)L_j(x)dx = \delta_{ij}c_j = \delta_{ij}\frac{2}{2j+1}
$$
(see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials)
whereas the weights for Gauss-Legendre are (for $n^\textrm{th}$ order GL quadrature)
$$
w_i = \frac{2}{(1-x_i)^2\left[L^{'}_n(x_i)\right]^2}
$$
where $x_i$ are the zeros of the $n^\textrm{th}$ order Legendre polynomial
(see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Legendre_quadrature).  These two are clearly different.

Comment: The answer is false. The questioner refers $L$ to be Lagrange polynomials and not Legendre polynomials. The statement should be correct.

Comment: The statement is still false.  In the statement they refer to Legendre, not Lagrange, and they mention "x" is a zero, whereas in the equation "x" is the variable of integration.

Comment: Sure this is a bit unpresize. However, the statement should be correct iff Lagrange polynomials with Legendre-Gauss distribution are considered. These polynomials are orthogonal.

Comment: Note that the roots of the Legendre polynomials exactly define these polynomials.